# Choose the correct statement(s) for uncountability of derived sets

Tags: real-analysis

A. A set is uncountable if its derived set is uncountable.
B. Derived set of an uncountable set is uncountable.
C. Non empty interior set of a set is open.
D. All of the above.
This is a multiple select question.

I considered a Set of Rational no., Now its derived set is R(Set of Real numbers) which is uncountable, but the set of rational numbers is countable.So option A must be false,Right?
Option B is true, if i take set of irrational numbers, which is uncountable and its derived set is R which is again uncountable.
How should i proceed option c?
Also What all are the property of derived sets?

Comment: What is a derived set?

Comment: derived set is the set of all limit points of a set

Comment: Are you considering only subsets of the real numbers (with the standard metric) or all metric spaces?